# Can DHCP and DNS both use .local on the same LAN?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, dhcp, fortigate

My local LAN machines are assigned IP addresses from a Fortigate 60D DHCP server.
The DHCP uses `.local` as its domain name.
I now started a DNS server, also running off the Fortigate 60D.

I'm reluctant to set the DNS domain name to also be `.local`, as it seems to me that this may cause clashes.

Am I being paranoid, or is my apprehension justified?

Comment: In my practice DHCP and DNS are always in the same domain

Comment: That depends on the Fortigate management software, if you can set it to return your DNS server's IP address with the DHCP return answer. This might require giving it a static IP address. The Fortigate manuals I can find on the Internet don't have the necessary info.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with DNS and DHCP using the same domain name. But the name `.local` is special; it is reserved for mDNS and you should not configure a DNS server to use the `.local`TLD. From RFC6762:

> This document specifies that the DNS top-level domain .local." is a
>   special domain with special semantics, namely that any fully qualified
>   name ending in ".local." is link-local, and names within this domain
>   are meaningful only on the link where they originate.